# How to Prevent text overlay

Tags: pine-script

How do you prevent text overlay when you are using plotshape
If conditions met
    Display buy
If second conduction met
    Display long

When both condition met, both of the text just stack on each other.  How do I prevent this from happening

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `\n` followed by a special non-printing character that doesn't get stripped out. Here we're using U+206A. While you don't see it in the following code's strings, it is there and can be copy/pasted:

```
//@version=4
study("Lift text", "", true)
// Use U+206A (Decimal 8298) as a non-printing space after the last "\n".
// The line will become difficult to edit in the editor, but the character will be there.
// You can use https://unicode-table.com/en/tools/generator/ to generate a copy/pastable character.
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, text="A")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, text="B\n ⁪")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, text="C\n⁪⁪\n⁪⁪")
plotshape(true, "", shape.arrowup, location.abovebar, text="D\n\n\n⁪")
```

[image]